# Emacs mode/method for logic symbol placement in text?

Tags: emacs

I would like to put actual logic symbols into my emacs buffers, e.g., the logic symbol "∀" or "∃" or "⇒", directly into my (fundamental) text or .org or whatever buffer. I found [xmsi-math-symbols-input.el](https://code.google.com/p/ergoemacs/source/browse/packages/xmsi-math-symbols-input.el?r=b962d1c4a48f3d3f589767de4bf00a19a8cdb122) at [ErgoEmacs](https://code.google.com/p/ergoemacs/), but I'm wondering if this is "best practice." Maybe the best practice is to just right Tex/Latex copy, especially if I'm doing org-mode?

Comment: latest version is at https://github.com/xahlee/xah-math-input , also on MELPA. If you want to define your own, can do OS wide or  many ways in emacs, by key or by abbrev, see http://xahlee.info/kbd/creating_apl_keyboard_layout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the corresponding Unicode characters normally in Emacs. Bind any that you want to any keys you want. For example:

```
(global-set-key [f2] "∀")
(global-set-key [f3] "∃")
(global-set-key [f4] "⇒")
```

To get the string with the char, you can use `C-x 8 RET` and type the name or code point of the Unicode char.  In other words, `C-x 8 RET` lets you insert any Unicode character.

For example, the Unicode code point for `∀` is 2200.  `C-x 8 RET 2200 RET` inserts a `∀` character.

And the Unicode name of `∀` is `FOR ALL`.  `C-x 8 RET for all RET` also inserts a `∀` character.

The reason you might want to bind a particular character to a key is for convenience - `C-x 8 RET` is very general, and generally slow.

Answer (score 2):

At least in org-mode, it is possible to [place special symbols](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) in an .org buffer just as their raw latex markup, e.g.:

```
\forall
```

becomes the UTF-8

```
∀
```

when you do C-c C-x \

... but this isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is with the `TeX` input method.  I.e. use `C-u C-\ TeX RET` after which typing `\forall` will insert the `∀` char.

[ Well, in reality , I have `TeX` set as my default coding-system, so I really only need to hit `C-\` to enable this input method.  ]